# Optimizing process relaunch

Tags: c, linux, performance, kernel

I need to relaunch a process repeatedly (by itself). Wanted to know if there is anything I can do to avoid a full exec.  Where does the initialized and uninitialized data segment initialization happens ?  Does it happen in the kernel space or in libc or in loader?  IS there anything I can do to leverage the fact that it is the same binary (as the running binary) that I am execing every time ?

Comment: I would prefer a solution that avoids a kernel change, preferably using LD_PRELOAD or any user space code change.  but if it is not possible, any kernel change solution would also be very useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want - "relaunch repeatedly by itself" is less than clear -  but the `exec` is easy enough to avoid.

Since you are already in the program image you want to relaunch you just need to `fork` new copies.  You can have a master copy whose one responsibility is to fork children and let the children run the actual program code that constitutes the real functionality.  Something like:

```
while ((! done)
{
    //wait on signal, fifo, socket, whatever

    if (somethingSaysWeAreDone)
        exit(0);

    if (fork == 0)
        break;
}

//children execute the rest of the program
```

Each child has a clean slate of segments other than the one or two variables above which they should never need anyway.  I don't see any way you can avoid a fork though and obviously you need some kind of mechanism to communicate to the "master" copy that it should reproduce.

Comment: If they had access to the source, couldn't they just put everything in a loop and call it a day? I was assuming they didn't have the source. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @ Matthew Adams, I couldn't determine what OP has access to.  I seized upon "or any user space code change" as meaning he had the source but maybe that's not what he meant.  If not, ignore.  No harm done.

Comment: Oh gotcha. Wasn't trying to be critical, just was a bit confused.

Comment: I dont have access to the code.  by user space code change, I mean changes in libc or any other library that could be done transparently with out changing the end binary.